# Kendo Dropdownlist Placeholder

Tags: angularjs, html, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using a kendo dropdownlist and I need a placeholder for the dropdownlist which shouldn't appear in the list when I select the dropdown. I tried using optionLabel but this value shows up in the list.

```
 var $dropdownElement;

    $dropdownElement = $("<input />");

    $dropdownElement.appendTo($dropdownContainer);
    $dropdownElement.kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: dropdown.items,
            optionLabel: "select your option", //shows as option in dropdown
            popup: {
                appendTo: $dropdownContainer
            }
    });
```

I will need a solution where I can add a placeholder and that value shouldn't be shown as an option in the dropdownlist.

Comment: I have something similar with a combo box. Not sure how it would work with a dropdownlist that is databound:    $dropdownElement.data("kendoComboBox").input.attr("placeholder","select option");

Comment: It is not the same. This is not supported out of the box. Try using the ddl events to hide the optionlabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find the first element in the dropwdownn list and hide it to make it look less chatty

```
$dropdownElement.getKendoDropDownList().list.find("li.k-item").first().hide();
```

[Plunker Dropdownlist (and combobox) example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wOHowpDKK9VZwDLfPOnR?p=preview)